# Xcode gives link error for Cordova project: 'no bitcode'

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, bitcode

I am trying to build a Cordova project with Xcode 7.1.1 and am getting a 'no bitcode' error from the linker:

```
ld: '/Users/billnoble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CUES-donxgdovpardqqbprhstonixixch/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a(CDVInvokedUrlCommand.o)' 
does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode 
enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), 
obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode
```

I have set Enable Bitcode to No in the build settings for both debug and release versions (as recommended in suggested solutions to this problem elsewhere) but this does not remove the link error.

I have installed the latest Corodova 3.9.2 release.

Comment: did you set it to no for all the targets? (where did you set the enable bit code to no?)

Comment: Under the enable bitcode setting in the project build settings there are two sub settings. One for release and one for debug. Both those are set to 'NO'.

Comment: did you try to clean your project, and/or remove all derived data? sometimes some compiled stuff sticks around ...

Comment: I did clean yes. Not sure what you mean by remove derived data?

Comment: try updating to latest cordova ios (4.0.0)